# POSTMAN - no cli option

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I wanted to run postman as cli mode, created the collection but under the runner option, I unable to find the cli option, also referred documentation, did the fresh install on other machines. Also setup the package via powershell. But under the run -> runner, only option is "Run manually" but "Automate runs via CLI" missing. I have tried with two Win10 64 machines.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `newman` is what you're looking for

Comment: Newman is going to help but they are talking about a new feature that will be part of V10. This isn't fully rolled out to all users yet.

Comment: Thank you, While doing research, I also came across Newman, but NODE.js was the prerequisites and, for my case, special permission was required to setup, so I thought to stick with standard cli options.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install "newman". Then you should export the postman collection and run the collection path with the "newman run" command.

This link may help you : [Installing and running Newman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/installing-running-newman/)